# Assign data to from TextBox to variable (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, binding

Into xaml I have textBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LoginName}" Style="{StaticResource myTextBox}" />
```

Now I want to assing this value to my string variable ("userLogin"):

```
private static string userLogin;
public static void SetUser()
{
        userLogin = LoginName.text; //ToString();
}
```

that later on into other method I will use this userLogin, as below:

```
static async Task<string> SomeTest() {
...
  if (method == "authenticate")
      jsonString = "{.... + userLogin + ...}";
...
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How correctly it's should be done? Maybe SetUser is not necessary?

Comment: why don't you just call LoginName.text in the second method

Comment: when I put this as you wrote then I got this error: "an object reference is required for the non-static field...."

Comment: My bad, I'm falling asleep here. Do you call userLogin at all? What is happening that indicates it is not working?

Comment: Or you can make userLogin static

Comment: I'm not sure...as the "login" will be used into other method would be good to have it into some variable

Comment: in xaml you use LoginName as a property (it's OK) but in code you use it as it's a control's name. Choose one way not mix two. Also remember that when changing text you must leave the textbox (default behaviour) or set updating the value on typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your binding (`Text="{Binding Path=LoginName}"`), there should be a public property called `LoginName` of type `string` in your data context (in your case, it seems to be the view itself):

```
public string LoginName { get; set; }

private static string userLogin;

public static void SetUser()
{
    // you can then use the property from here
    // (or remove `userLogin` altogether, as it does not add any value)
    // notice that we're not doing `.text` or anything; it's already a `string`
    userLogin = LoginName;
}
```

Also, as Leonid Malyshev [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943447/assign-data-to-from-textbox-to-variable-c-wpf#comment90837724_51943447), if you want `LoginName` to be updated on each keystroke, you need to explicitly specify it in the binding as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LoginName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource myTextBox}" />
```

Otherwise, the value will only be updated when the `TextBox` loses focus (default behavior).

---

Another way to solve the problem is to remove the binding and reference the `TextBox` by a name:

```
<TextBox x:Name="LoginName" Style="{StaticResource myTextBox}" />
```

You can then access it directly from the code:

```
private static string userLogin;

public static void SetUser()
{
    userLogin = LoginName.Text; // with an uppercase T!
}
```

Comment: I just want to take "login" once and the use into my method......anyway thank you @Julien for the great explanations!